# Place a control on Wpf Datagrid at a specific location

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I am trying to place a button,shape or any control or `UserControl` on a `Datagrid` as an overlay.what i want is to place it at a specific row and column index. For example i want to place it at row no 2 and it should cover 2 columns , column no 3 and 4. Something like this blow.

```
<Canvas Grid.Row="1" Name="CanvasContainer" Background="CadetBlue" AllowDrop="True" Drop="Canvas_Drop">
            <DataGrid Name="DataGrid" AllowDrop="True" 
                      Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=CanvasConstatainer}"
                      Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=CanvasContainer}">
            </DataGrid>
            <Button Visibility="Visible" Name="LayerBtn" Width="100" Height="30"
                    PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="btn_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp"
                    PreviewMouseMove="btn_PreviewMouseMove"
                    MouseMove="btn_MouseMove"
                    PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="btn_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Canvas.Left="111" Canvas.Top="69">
                    Layer
            </Button>    
 </Canvas>
```

I have written just this peace of code. see i am using button as overlay but it could be any control or a `usercontrol`. I want to do something like below shown in image.

[image]

Comment: You mean you have already achieved what you need with a Button as example - and the question is to allow it to be any general control? Well most (2D) Controls have same parent classes** thats your clue.

Comment: @PrateekShrivastava no sir ! i havent achieved it in wpf yet ! the image i have shared is a wfa form. but i want to do same in wpf.

Comment: @mm8 any idea sir ?

Answer (score 0):

I think it can't be done. While using DataGrid you have to define what type of columns you are using. DataGridTextBoxColumn is usually put by default when passing Data by a DataTAble, it considers all Text.

But you can define other types of columns, for example DataGridComboBox column or DataGridCheckboxColumn that may let you do atleast partially what you wanted to do there.

Nevertheless you can define your own column that does exactly what you want. But that's something not easy to do.